# Unable to resolve path to module 'react'. (import/no-unresolved)

Tags: reactjs, babeljs, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

Seems like i am missing something here, it should work without errors but **eslint** keeps throwing the following:

**Unable to resolve path to module 'react'. (import/no-unresolved)**

**Missing file extension for "react" (import/extensions)**

when trying to `import React from 'react'`

here is some debug info:

**package.json**

```
{
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "16.3.2",
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.4.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^3.4.2",
    "@storybook/addons": "^3.4.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^3.4.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0"
  }
}
```

**.eslintrc**

```
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "extends": ["airbnb", "prettier"],
  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "node": true,
    "es6": true
  }
}
```

**.babelrc**

```
{
  "presets": ["env", "react"]
}
```

**editor**: atom v1.26.1

Thanks.

Answer (score 17):

If you're using React Native it may help to add `.native.js` as an allowed extension in your `.eslintrc` file.
Also, if you're using Typescript then `.ts` and `.tsx` will help too.

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx", ".native.js"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, this was my issue. It didnt have .d.ts files.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55280867/470749 seems to agree with you. I haven't gotten mine working yet. I still see `Missing file extension "ts" for "./types"  import/extensions`

Answer (score 5):

I had some problem i removed nodo_modules directory from project and run yarn install / npm install

Answer (score 2):

I think it complains because `react` should be in `dependencies`:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.2",
    "react-dom": "16.3.2",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "^3.4.2",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^3.4.2",
    "@storybook/addons": "^3.4.2",
    "@storybook/react": "^3.4.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.3",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.26.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^16.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^2.9.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.7.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What did you have to do to install it correctly? @jalal246

Comment: @Sankofa just move "react" line to dependencies from devDependencies and then run `npm install`. If you do not have react installed at all install it with `npm install react`

Answer (score 2):

I installed **react** and **react-dom** using `npm i -E react react-dom` trying to install the exact version which didn't install it correctly.

`npm i react react-dom -D` solved the problem.

Answer (score 2):

This also happened to me. In my case, it was because I was running `npm` version 6, but a team member had installed a new library via `npm` version 7. Version 7 uses a new version for the lock file format.

Our solution was to make sure everyone was running the same `npm` version so that our `package-lock.json` files would be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

try to add in **eslintrc**:

```
"rules": {
   "import/no-unresolved": [2, { "devDependencies": true }],
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have experience with the same problem.

In my case, this error appear because I pull new update from the remote repository and it's bring new dependencies.

To solve this, I just install that dependencies with `npm install`

Answer (score 0):

Just comment out the import and run. Then again remove the comments. It worked for me.