# Using eslint with typescript - Unable to resolve path to module

Tags: typescript, eslint

I have this import in my file **app.spec.ts**:

```
import app from './app';
```

Which causes this Typescript error

```
2:17  error  Unable to resolve path to module './app'  import/no-unresolved
```

**./app.ts** does exist, but I have not compiled the .ts file into a .js file. As soon as I compile the .ts file to a .js, the error goes away.

However, since eslint is supposed to work with typescript, it should resolve modules with the .ts and not the .js.

I've also added the typescript information in my `eslint` config file:

```
"parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
"parserOptions": {
    "project": "./tsconfig.json"
}
```

How can I config eslint in such a way that it tries to resolve modules with the .ts and not the .js?

**EDIT #1**

Content of `app.ts`:

```
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import express from 'express';
import graphqlHTTP from 'express-graphql';
import { buildSchema } from 'graphql';

const app = express();

const schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
        hello: String
    }
`);
const root = { hello: () => 'Hello world!' };

app.use(bodyParser());
app.use('/graphql', graphqlHTTP({
    schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true,
}));

export default app;
```

Comment: Have you added `"plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"]`? Docs https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/tree/master/packages/eslint-plugin

Comment: Hey @Jasmonate, thanks for the answer! So I just added this config, and while I can now do some Typescript-specific linting, it does not solve my problem. I still get `Unable to resolve path to module './app'`

Comment: Have you tried adding this into your .eslintrc?

```settings: {
    'import/resolver': 'webpack'
  }``` 
(I'm assuming the code builds OK. If not, you will need to tell webpack to resolve .ts/.tsx files as well, which means adding something like:
```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.ts']
  }
};
``` or whatever file extensions you want to be able to import!
)

Comment: The above comment is incomplete, I'm afraid! I ran out of editing time having pressed enter too soon! The
 ```module.exports = { resolve: { extensions: ['.js', '.ts'] } }; ``` bit should be in your webpack config!

Comment: Can you add the content of your `app.ts` file ?

Comment: Hey @Abulafia! Unfortunately, I am not using webpack...

Comment: @Eastrall I edited the question with the content of `app.ts` :)

Comment: If all else fails, you can try deleting `node_modules`, reinstalling, and restarting TS server

Answer (score 620, accepted):

You can set the ESLint module import resolution by adding this snippet to your `.eslintrc.json` configuration file:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },
  ...
}
```

More informations about resolvers: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#resolvers.

Comment: I believe the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56696478/1179377) is the right solution for this.

Comment: This seemed to solve the `Unable to resolve path to module` error, but now I'm still getting a bunch of `Missing file extension "tsx" for [...]`

Comment: Ahh, `'import/extensions': 0,` helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56064609/unable-to-resolve-relative-module-paths-when-eslint-run-from-sub-folder/56192351#comment115802229_56192351

Comment: It's one of those days! I had this problem, used this solution, and it didn't work. Tried it again several hours later and then it works. Weird!

Comment: In my `eslintrc.js` config file, the `"import/resolver"` object needed to sit within the `"rules"` node, not the `"settings"` node as described above.

Comment: I needed to install:
 npm install eslint-import-resolver-alias --save-dev

Comment: How do you do this with Flat Config?

Answer (score 233):

I had the same problem and I was only able to fix it by adding the typescript plugin to `.eslintrc`,  using the [`extends` option in `.eslintrc`](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import#typescript)

```
  extends: [
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
  ],
```

Comment: Thanks! Adding `"plugin:import/typescript"` is what fixed it for me.

Comment: Note that you need to 1. place "plugin:import/typescript" after "airbnb-base". 2. Remember to add `"import"` in `plugins` section.

Comment: now i get `Missing file extension "ts" for <file>`

Comment: ^ fixed with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59268871/12658818

Comment: For some reason by just having "plugin:import/typescript", did not solved this problem for me. The solution was to use this: https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/eslint-import-resolver-typescript

Comment: If anyone tries this and gets the error `Failed to load config plugin:import/typescript`, make sure you're not on an ancient version of `eslint-plugin-import` like I was. The typescript config was added somewhere between 2.14.0 and 2.25.2.

Comment: I think this is the best answer!

Comment: Notably the issue I had with this seems to be when I have those first two, the errors and warnings, they are still getting used, and since they are non-typescript, introduce the error. The typescript flavor correctly resolves the pathing based on my tsconfig. Now I am concerned about missing all the other vanilla lint rules. Sigh

Answer (score 145):

This was the only solution that worked for me.

First, you need to install this package:

```sh
yarn add -D eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```

Then add this to your `.eslintrc` file so it can load the alias settings from your `tsconfig.json` into ESLint:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {}
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: This is the only one that worked for me when using a monorepo and a path alias to a different package.

Comment: @Semx11, Same here!

Comment: it's only solution for me thx ;)

Comment: ` "typescript": {} ` did the trick for me.

Comment: Thanks for this solution, the other ones didn't really help in my use case

Comment: this worked for me, one thing to note is if you are using an IDE and the error is shown by the IDE, make sure that you check it with the command line, cause your IDE may be misconfigured.

Comment: Thanks! Missing `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` was the issue!

Comment: this solved the path alias issue in a react-native cli project

Comment: this is what did the trick for me. I was missing this step. Thanks

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 118):

This does it for me:

**.eslintrc.js**

```
{
    ...
    settings: {
        ...
        'import/resolver': {
            node: {
                extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
                moduleDirectory: ['node_modules', 'src/'],
            },
        },
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what worked for me; even including the "plugin:import/*" extensions didn't do anything. The `moduleDirectory` line pointing to `'src/'` was the key to get this working on my end.

Comment: This worked for me as well. Note that HAD to add the "moduleDirectory" key.

Comment: Adding the moduleDirectory: ['node_modules', 'myModules/'] indeed helped. I've seen a partial version of this solution without  'moduleDirectory' property and it didn't work. This one did the trick.

Comment: works after adding moduleDirectory: ['node_modules', 'src/']

Comment: This worked for me using the same config in .eslintrc.json in the typescript react project.

Comment: This worked for me with [Quasar v1](https://v1.quasar.dev/) (`quasar create <project> --branch v1`) and `airbnb-base` [ESLint config](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base).

Comment: this works with nextjs, thanks

Comment: Add my voice to also say this is the only solution that also worked for me after trying pretty much everything else that I came across to solve this problem

Answer (score 41):

In my case I just had to change

```
import { SetOptional, SetRequired } from 'type-fest';
```

to

```
import type { SetOptional, SetRequired } from 'type-fest';
```

Comment: @pedro_A you are the real MVP!

Comment: so much better than messing around with eslint/ts configs!

Comment: Who would've thought. Can you explain why this solves the problem, or what exactly the problem was?

Comment: @Bergi Hello, unfortunately I don't know for sure hahaha... It feels like I wrote this answer years ago... The fact that this solution works makes me suspect it's a bug with typescript-eslint.

Comment: It might have something to do with elision of type-only imports, somehow being done at the wrong time. Maybe the import resolver sees only an empty file (since everything was elided)? Or maybe it has something to do with modules whose typings use namespaces, such as [type-fest](https://github.com/sindresorhus/type-fest/blob/b40cb9c8e6dbea84bc99ec9e37bdd636c5cc6565/source/basic.d.ts#L39-L43), since the `import type` syntax interferes with those... (open [the PR that introduced the syntax](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/35200) and search for _"If the symbol is a namespace"_ there)

Comment: I believe this is the proper solution here. `type-fest` might not have any real js and is just a ts declaration file, which causes eslint to complain.

Answer (score 31):

When using **"eslint": "6.8.0"** with **"typescript": "3.8.3"** besides adding the following to `.eslintrc`:

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "paths": ["src"],
      "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    }
  },
}
```

You also need to add this line to `tsconfig.json` under `compilerOptions`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
  ...
  // Base directory to resolve non-relative module names.
  "baseUrl": "src",
  ...
}
```

Comment: Greatly appreciated to add the `baseUrl` options, saved my day

Comment: In my case I had to add .d.ts to the list- the package csstypes only contains an index.d.ts:

            "settings": {
                "import/resolver": {
                    "node": {
                        "paths": [
                            "src"
                        ],
                        "extensions": [
                            ".js",
                            ".jsx",
                            ".d.ts",
                            ".ts",
                            ".tsx"
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }

Comment: This can also solve the case when the eslint configuration is shared between several projects and therefore located in a top-level folder. Listing all projects' paths in the `paths` property solves the eslint error.

Answer (score 25):

If you've updated your `.eslintrc` and `tsconfig.json` files as suggested in the other answers, and you still have the problem - **restart vscode**.

Comment: That worked for me!! Thank you :)

Comment: It didn't work for me.

Answer (score 13):

for those who use `babel-module` just add the `extensions` so it would be something like this:

```
      "babel-module": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
        "alias": {
          "app": "./app"
        }
      }
```

Comment: Indeed. My "babel-module" had only {}

Answer (score 12):

Both **ts** and **eslint** were barking at me, so I had to add the following to my **.eslintrc** file:

```
{ 
    ...
    "rules": {
        ....
        "import/extensions": "off"
    },
    "settings": {
        ....
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I needed both the "settings" and the "rules", as described in this answer. Thanks!

Comment: barking!! Hats off

Answer (score 7):

First add `"plugin:import/typescript"` under extends like below :

```
"extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "plugin:import/typescript"
 ],
```

then below under rules

```
"rules": {
        "import/extensions": [
            "error",
            "ignorePackages",
            {
                "ts": "never"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

When importing `locale` files for Angular (e.g. `import localeEn from '@angular/common/locales/en';`), I had to allow the `.mjs` extension.

Here is an excerpt of my `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
  ...
  "extends": [
    ...
    "plugin:import/recommended",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
    ...
  ],
  "settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".ts", ".mjs"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    ...
  }
  ...
```

---

Edit:

When importing `HttpClient` or `HttpClientModule`, the error came back.
I found out that adding the `.d.ts` extension to the list fixed the issue, which also make more sense than the `.mjs` (that is no longer needed).

So here is my new `.eslintrc.json`:

```json
  ...

  {
    "files": ["*.ts"],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
      "project": ["tsconfig.json"],
      "createDefaultProgram": true
    },
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
          "extensions": [".ts", ".d.ts"]
        }
      }
    },
    "extends": [
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:import/recommended",
      "plugin:import/typescript",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:@angular-eslint/recommended",
      "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat",
      "plugin:@angular-eslint/ng-cli-compat--formatting-add-on",
      "plugin:@angular-eslint/template/process-inline-templates"
    ],
    "rules": {
      ...
    }
  }

  ...
```

(I'm using @angular-eslint, but you may have a different `extends` list)

Answer (score 6):

In my case, ESLint wasn't able to resolve the types installed from `DefinitelyTyped` (`@type/` packages), so I had to specify where to find them in `.eslintrc` like this:

```json
"import/resolver": {
    "typescript": {},
    "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".ts"],
        "paths": ["node_modules/", "node_modules/@types"]
    }
},
```

I also added `"typescript": {}`, which is basically for using configs from `tsconfig.json` and I have `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` installed for it to work.

Comment: alternatively, you can just tell it where your node modules are with `'node': { 'moduleDirectory': 'node_modules' }`

Answer (score 5):

My situation with ts monorepo was that I was not getting lint errors in IDE, all aliases were resolved alright, but as soon as I run eslint on one of the projects, I was getting

```
error  Unable to resolve path to module
```

It is important to show eslint path to each of your package's `tsconfig` file.

To sum up and for those with TS, aliases and monorepo:

- install `eslint-import-resolver-typescript`
- add to `eslintrc.js` settings (this will help ide and eslint to figure aliases and stuff):

```js
    'import/resolver': {
      node: {
        paths: 'packages/*/src',
        extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.ts', '.tsx'],
      },
      typescript: {
        alwaysTryTypes: true,
        project:[
         path.resolve(__dirname, '.tsconfig.json'), // root tsconfig
         path.resolve(__dirname, './packages/projA/tsconfig.json'),
         path.resolve(__dirname, './packages/projB/tsconfig.json'),
         /* ...rest of projects path to its tsconfig */
        ],
      },
```

- add to `eslintrc.js` extends:

```js
{
 ...,
   'plugin:import/recommended',
   'plugin:import/typescript',
}
```

- add to `eslintrc.js` plugins:

```js
  plugins: ['@typescript-eslint', ..., 'import'],
```

- add to `eslintrc.js` parserOptions (same as to settings) this will help eslint:

```js
        project: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, '.tsconfig.json'), // root tsconfig
          path.resolve(__dirname, './packages/projA/tsconfig.json'),
          path.resolve(__dirname, './packages/projB/tsconfig.json'),
          /* ...rest of projects path to its tsconfig */
        ],
```

Comment: Nice! The `path.resolve(__dirname, '.tsconfig.json')` in `project` resolved it for me.

Answer (score 2):

In case, if anyone needs to support child directory as well. For an example, it supports

1. src/components/input => components/input
2. src/api/external/request => external/request

   ```
   "settings": {
     "import/resolver": {
       "node": {
         "paths": ["src", "src/api"],
         "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
       }
     }
   }
   ```

This is working example for **eslint ^6.1.0**

Answer (score 2):

I had to add the typescript import to extends and then turn off the imports in the rules:

```
"extends": {
    "plugin:import/typescript"
},
"rules": {
    "import/extensions": "off"
}
```

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem only it turn off the rule

Answer (score 2):

For me it was just simply installing [eslint-import-resolver-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-node):

```
yarn add -D eslint-import-resolver-node
# or
npm install eslint-import-resolver-node --save-dev
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, this error was caused by using [eslint-config-airbnb](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb). It isn't set up to work properly with typescript. The best fix for that (from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67610259/503402)) is to install [eslint-config-airbnb-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript). The npm page includes the setup instructions, which involves tweaking your eslint config to load it and pointing it at your typescript config.

Note that if you used [create-react-app](https://create-react-app.dev/) to set up your app, you'll have an `eslintConfig` block in `package.json`. You need to have **one** ESLint config. If you create an `.eslintrc` to set up typescript linting, you should delete the block from `package.json` and move any config from there into the one config file.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was that the paths were not correctly resolving for the source folder. To solve the problem, I added the father of the source folder to the paths as well.

Instead of:

```html
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      "paths": ["src"]
    }
  }
}
```

I made the following modification:

```html
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
      "paths": ["src", "client/src"]
    }
  }
}
```

Explanation:
By adding the "client/src" path, the resolver can now correctly locate the files within that directory when importing or resolving modules. This change resolved the path resolution issue I was facing in my project.

(Optional: If applicable, mention where the "settings" block should be placed in your project's configuration file, e.g., webpack.config.js, tsconfig.json, etc.)

I hope this solution helps others who encounter a similar problem!

Answer (score 1):

In 2023 this helps me

```js
  env: { browser: true, es2020: true, node: true },
  extends: [
    'plugin:react/recommended',
    'airbnb',
    'airbnb-typescript',
    'airbnb/hooks',
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:react-hooks/recommended',
    'plugin:import/recommended',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'prettier',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: './tsconfig.json',
    ecmaVersion: 2018,
    sourceType: 'module',
    ecmaFeatures: {
      jsx: true,
    },
  },
    // Airbnb disable eslint-import-resolver-typescript
    // See: https://github.com/iamturns/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript#why-is-importno-unresolved-disabled
    // But, To support the tsconfig baseUrl and paths for aliasese that we uses,
    // you need this package
    // See configuration here
    // https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/eslint-import-resolver-typescript#installation

    'import/parsers': {
      '@typescript-eslint/parser': ['.ts', '.tsx'],
    },
    'import/resolver': {
      typescript: {
        alwaysTryTypes: true,
      },
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to delete the eslint cache, and then it worked like a charm. (Our yarn script is

`"lint:eslint": "eslint . --cache --cache-location '../../eslintcache/' --format stylish"`

.)

Answer (score 0):

I´ve spend a lot of hours trying several approaches from this page. But however this did not solve my problem. In my case I am using more then one tsconfig file in a large project.

I was adding `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` to my project:

```
npm install eslint-import-resolver-typescript
```

Afterwards I added this to my eslintrc:

```
    settings: {
        "import/resolver": {
            typescript: {
                project: ["./path/to/config.json", "./path/to/config2.json", "./path/to/config3.json"] // Pfad zu deiner tsconfig.json-Datei
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add this to `extends`:

   ```json
   "extends": [
     "airbnb-typescript",
   ]
   ```
2. Add this to `parserOptions`:

   ```json
   "parserOptions": {      
      "project": "./tsconfig.json"
    },
   ```
3. Be sure to install the `dev` module:

   ```
   npm i --save-dev eslint-config-airbnb-typescript
   ```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -18):

### Awesome people know how to solve this by oneliner in 2022:

```
"rules": {
  "import/extensions": [ "error", "ignorePackages", { "": "never" } ]
}
```

Comment: ignoring a problem and fixing a problem are very different solutions.

Comment: @ChunkyChunk: But the accepted one didn't work during my writing.

Comment: Nice title as well, nice job!