# Unable to resolve relative module paths when eslint run from sub-folder

Tags: javascript, eslint

When I run eslint from the root folder of my repo everything runs fine, with no errors.

But when I run from a subfolder I get a ton of import/no-unresolved that don't happen when I run from root:

```
/reporoot/subfolder0/subfolder1/MyFile.js
  11:8   error  Unable to resolve path to module 'foo'  import/no-unresolved
  11:8   error  Missing file extension for "foo"        import/extensions
  14:97  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'foo'  import/no-unresolved
  14:97  error  Missing file extension for "foo"        import/extensions
```

Doesn't matter how I run. e.g.:

This will work:

```
cd /reporoot
eslint .
```

All of these commands will fail with error shown above:

```
cd subfolder0
eslint .
```

or

```
eslint subfolder0
```

or

```
eslint /reporoot/subfolder0/subfolder1/MyFile.js
```

Any idea what the issue is, or thoughts about how to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

This is probably a problem with absolute paths in your imports according to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/1180).

Try to set this in your `.eslintrc.json` (Or convert it to any other filetype if you don't use JSON)

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
            "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
        }
    }
}
```

If the above doesn't work and you just want to get rid of these errors just add this instead:

```
"settings": {
    "import/no-unresolved": 0, // Turn off "Unable to resolve path to module ..." error
    "import/extensions": 0 // Turn off "Missing file extension for ..." error
}
```

Disabling this is not that big of a deal anyway because linters are pretty well known for having problems with pathing.

Comment: `'import/extensions': 0,` worked for me in `rules` but not in `settings`.