# Typescript eslint - Missing file extension "ts" import/extensions

Tags: node.js, typescript, eslint

I have a simple Node/Express app made with Typescript.
And eslint give me the error

```
Missing file extension "ts" for "./lib/env" import/extensions
```

Here is my .eslintrc file

```
    {
  "extends": [
    "airbnb",
    "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
    "prettier",
    "prettier/react",
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint", "prettier", "import"],
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "typescript": {
        "directory": "./tsconfig.json"
      },
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },
  "rules": {
    "@typescript-eslint/indent": [2, 2],
    "no-console": "off",
    "import/no-unresolved": [2, { "commonjs": true, "amd": true }],
    "import/named": 2,
    "import/namespace": 2,
    "import/default": 2,
    "import/export": 2
  }
}
```

I have installed eslint-plugin-import & eslint-import-resolver-typescript.
And I cannot figure out why, I got that error.

Comment: https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1558

Comment: a note for myself: I solve this before. This is problem about `airbnb`, and can be oneliner solved using `"import/extensions": [ "error", "ignorePackages", { "": "never" } ]`.

Answer (score 364, accepted):

Add the following code to `rules`:

```
"rules": {
   "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
   ]
}
```

`airbnb` ESLint [config](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/blob/master/packages/eslint-config-airbnb-base/rules/imports.js#L139) leads the problem.

Comment: Worked! Thanks. (other readers: make sure you put it under "rules" not "settings"...)

Comment: but but what does this do?

Comment: @JulianSoto For whom using 'eslint-config-airbnb-base' in there typescript project, there is a rule to 'Ensure consistent use of file extension within the import path', which leads the problem. So we can just overwrite it to fit typescript project.

Comment: with eslint 7.27.0 i get this error `Configuration for rule "import/extensions" is invalid: Severity should be one of the following: 0 = off, 1 = warn, 2 = error (you passed '"error"')`

Comment: replace "error" with 2.

Comment: Eslint does not have such rule. You would need to install https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import first.

Comment: This just disables `import/extensions` entirely. Pointless answer.

Comment: for me helped only when added `{ "": "never", "ts": "never" }`

Answer (score 179):

I know this is late, but if you're extending the Airbnb rules you can use [eslint-config-airbnb-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-config-airbnb-typescript). Please refer to the project page for the latest instructions. Here's the gist of it as of March 2022:

Install

```sh
npm install -D eslint-config-airbnb-typescript
```

ESLint config file

using React - add 'airbnb-typescript' after 'airbnb'

```json
extends: [
  'airbnb',
+ 'airbnb-typescript'
]
```

without React - add 'airbnb-typescript/base' after 'airbnb-base'

```json
extends: [
  'airbnb-base',
+ 'airbnb-typescript/base'
]
```

set **parserOptions.project** to path of your `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  extends: ['airbnb', 'airbnb-typescript'],
+ parserOptions: {
+   project: './tsconfig.json'
+ }
}
```

---

**NOTE: Prior to August 2021, you would need to also do the following tasks.**
These instructions are remaining here for historical reference only. You should not need to do this any more.

First uninstall the old one and add the new one:

```sh
# uninstall whichever one you're using
npm uninstall eslint-config-airbnb
npm uninstall eslint-config-airbnb-base

# install the typescript one
npm install -D eslint-config-airbnb-typescript
```

Then update your ESlint config, remove the old Airbnb from the "extends" section and add the new one:

```json
extends: ["airbnb-typescript"]
```

Comment: Thanks! Running `npm install -D eslint-config-airbnb-typescript` and adding `'airbnb-typescript'` fixed for me.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Thanks for taking the time to update your original answer

Comment: npm install eslint-config-airbnb-typescript \
            @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@^5.13.0 \
            @typescript-eslint/parser@^5.0.0 \
            --save-dev
I can't install the package, got the error: https://imgur.com/rG8Zkzx

Comment: What if I have one eslintrc.js file in a monorepo, where some packages have react and some do not?

Comment: @cyrf - monorepos are a whole other game. I generally keep a single eslint file for the entire repo - you should be able to create a single config that works for react and non-react projects. The other approach is to have a one or more "base" configs in your root project and you import/extend those in individual packages in your monorepo.

Answer (score 27):

This is a strange solution, but I've added `"": "never"` and it worked for me (https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1573).

```
"rules": {
   "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "": "never",
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: Strangely enough this was the only solution that worked for me. Does anyone know why the empty quote marks are needed?

Comment: @Hazy I can assume that this is a bug in the webpack of one of the packages/extensions, but I don't know the exact answer. https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1573#issuecomment-565973643 – here is the guy who found this solution. Seems, he has no answer as well, but he described how he came to it.

Comment: in my case, it also helped

Comment: If you have this problem in VS Code: 
`"eslint.workingDirectories": [{ "mode": "auto" }]`
to my settings.json fixed the issue for me, without changing the eslint rules

Comment: Why is it working like that?

Answer (score 13):

Important to add import extension and parser to **.eslintrc**

```
    "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Further add to rules:

```
 "import/extensions": [
  "error",
  "ignorePackages",
  {
    "js": "never",
    "jsx": "never",
    "ts": "never",
    "tsx": "never"
  }
]



enter code here
```

Answer (score 5):

got this working by bundling all answers I found on internet:

this is the end result for me:

```
{
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"],
    "import/parsers": {
      "@typescript-eslint/parser": [".ts", ".tsx"]
    },
    "import/resolver": {
      "node": {
        "extensions": [".js", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
      }
    }
  },

  "env": {
    "browser": true,
    "es2021": true
  },

  "extends": ["plugin:react/recommended", "airbnb"],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "parserOptions": {
    "ecmaFeatures": {
      "jsx": true
    },
    "ecmaVersion": 12,
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "plugins": ["import", "react", "@typescript-eslint"],
  "rules": {
    "no-console": 1,
    "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never",
        "mjs": "never"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

im using react native btw. if u're using something different just removing react related should be enough

Answer (score 3):

If you're like me trying to configure babel, legacy Javascript, and new typescript files and attempting to enable extension free imports on `*.ts` then I was running into [this ESLint issue](https://github.com/benmosher/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1615#issuecomment-577500405) (where I also found below solution):

In addition to the `rules` config:

```
"rules": {
   "import/extensions": [
      "error",
      "ignorePackages",
      {
        "js": "never",
        "mjs": "never",
        "jsx": "never",
        "ts": "never",
        "tsx": "never"
      }
   ]
}
```

You also need an additional settings entry in your `.eslintrc.js`:

```
  "settings": {
    "import/extensions": [".js", ".mjs", ".jsx", ".ts", ".tsx"]
  },
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Following is a similar error that can be thrown due to '~' in imports:

[image]

> Missing file extension for "~/path/"
> eslintimport/extensions\

### Solution 1:

This issue can be resolved by configuring tsconfig.json and .eslintrc.js as follows.

**tsconfig.json**

```
...
“paths”: {
 “~*”: [“./src/*”],
},
...
```

**.eslintrc.js**

```
...
settings: {
  'import/resolver': {
     alias: {
       map: [['~', './src/']],
       extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.tsx'],
     },
   },
},
...
```

### Solution 2:

**If the error still persists**, then probably you must have opened the project in another directory other than the root directory (the directory where tsconfig.json and .eslintrc.js are located). Therefore opening the directory other than the root directory can confuse the eslint in identifying the path correctly, and throw the above error.

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into this because I was doing:

```js
import Ham from "./Ham.tsx"       // bad!
```

I needed to do:

```js
import Ham from "./Ham"           // good!
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was extending monorepo ESLint configs, and had `airbnb-base` loading after the package in which I was disabling that rule. So I just had to load it last.

Answer (score 0):

My issue persisted even with all the typescript properties in my `.eslintrc`.

#### .eslintrc

```json
"extends": [
    "airbnb-base",
    "airbnb-typescript/base"
  ],
  "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
  "plugins": ["@typescript-eslint"],
```

I was able to fix the issue by adding this to my webpack config:

#### webpack.config.json

```json
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.tsx', '.ts', '.js'],
}
```

Source: https://smartdevpreneur.com/the-three-easiest-ways-to-fix-the-missing-file-extension-tsx-error/

Answer (score 0):

for eslint@^8, I just put `*.js` into the  `overrides.files`, such as:

```
    ...
    overrides: [
        {
            // files: ['*.ts', '*.mts', '*.cts'],
            files: ['*.ts', '*.mts', '*.cts', '*.js'],
            plugins: [
                //
                'eslint-plugin-tsdoc',
                '@typescript-eslint',
            ],
    ...
```

the lint error massage around the line which import a js file, `Missing file extension "ts" for "....` gone.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `eslint-import-resolver-typescript` plugin to add TypeScript support to an existing `eslint-plugin-import` plugin in your project by using the following steps:

1. Install the plugin:
   `npm i -D eslint-import-resolver-typescript`

> NOTE: Please install `eslint-plugin-import` and
> `@typescript-eslint/parser` if you have not already. These are
> required for adding `.tsx` file import support with ESLint and
> Typescript-ESLint.
> 2. Add the following value at the "root" of your .eslintrc.json file:

```
"settings": {
    "import/resolver": {
        "typescript": {
            "alwaysTryTypes": true
        }
    }
}
```

3. Turn off the rule for specific extensions:

```
"rules": {
    "import/extensions": [
        "error",
        "always",
        {
            "pattern": {
                "js": "never",
                "ts": "never",
                "jsx": "never",
                "tsx": "never"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Hopefully that should do the trick.

For further clarification, you can also check out the links below:

- [Article on how to fix missing file extension error](https://smartdevpreneur.com/the-three-easiest-ways-to-fix-the-missing-file-extension-tsx-error/)
- [eslint-import-resolver-typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-import-resolver-typescript)