# Nextjs trying to find a file that doesn't exist anymore

Tags: next.js

I changed a file name from `columns.tsx` to `columns.ts` but Nextjs is still looking for the `columns.tsx` file. If I rename the file back to `columns.tsx`, it's now trying to find the `columns.ts` version.

This is while running `next dev`. I tried `next build` but without success.

If I make a copy of the file to have one `columns.ts` and one `columns.tsx` then it works.

Any clue as to why it happens and how to fix it?

```
wait  - compiling...
error - ./components/ui/tables/ReactTable/columns.tsx
Error: Failed to read source code from [...]/components/ui/tables/ReactTable/columns.tsx

Caused by:
    No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

Comment: Hi, i think this error occur because of EsLint rules. i hope this answer can help https://stackoverflow.com/a/59268871/7369564 or you can try allowing custom extensions by https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/custom-page-extensions

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I solved it by deleting the `.next` folder that includes the cache.

Comment: Solved the issue for a refoctured file that was moved to a sub directory and exposed by an index.ts for me.

Comment: Why does this fix the issue?