# Unable to resolve path to module when using .tsx with absolute paths in next js

Tags: reactjs, typescript, eslint, tslint

I have installed `eslint` for a `next.js` project which uses typescript and absolute paths.
When I try to import a component which has a `.tsx` extension using the absolute path I get the following eslint error.

> Unable to resolve path to module 'componentsFolder/MyComponentFile'.eslintimport/no-unresolved

The code works fine and only eslint gives a red warning

I have followed the solutions described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198502/using-eslint-with-typescript-unable-to-resolve-path-to-module/56696478#56696478), how ever nothing seems to work.

**The current state of my eslint.json is as follows.**

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es2021": true
    },
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "airbnb"
    ],
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 12,
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "extensions": [
                    ".js",
                    ".jsx",
                    ".ts",
                    ".tsx"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "rules": {
        "react/react-in-jsx-scope": "off",
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": [
            1,
            {
                "extensions": [
                    ".jsx",
                    ".tsx"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "no-underscore-dangle": 0
    }
}
```

The tsconfig.json file is as follows.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "next-env.d.ts",
    "**/*.ts",
    "**/*.tsx"
  ]
}
```