# eslint / typescript: Unable to resolve path to module

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, lint

My `.eslintrc.json` is:

```
{
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "commonjs": true,
        "es6": true,
        "node": true,
        "jest": true
    },
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "sourceType": "module"
    },
    "plugins": [
        "react",
        "prettier",
        "import"
    ],
    "extends": [
        "airbnb",
        "airbnb/hooks",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:import/errors",
        "plugin:import/warnings",
        "plugin:import/typescript",
        "prettier"
    ],
    "root": true,
    "rules": {
        "no-const-assign": 1,
        "no-extra-semi": 0,
        "semi": 0,
        "no-fallthrough": 0,
        "no-empty": 0,
        "no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs": 0,
        "no-redeclare": 0,
        "no-this-before-super": 1,
        "no-unreachable": 1,
        "no-use-before-define": 0,
        "constructor-super": 1,
        "curly": 0,
        "eqeqeq": 0,
        "func-names": 0,
        "valid-typeof": 1,
        "import/extensions": 0,
        "react/jsx-filename-extension": 0,
        // note you must disable the base rule as it can report incorrect errors
        "no-shadow": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-shadow": [
            1
        ],
        "no-unused-vars": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars": 1,
        "no-undef": 0,
        "jsx-a11y/click-events-have-key-events": 0,
        "jsx-a11y/no-static-element-interactions": 0,
        "@typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types": 0,
        "react/button-has-type": 0,
        "react/require-default-props": 0,
        "react/prop-types": 0,
        "react-hooks/exhaustive-deps": 0,
        "react/jsx-props-no-spreading": 0
    },
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "node": {
                "extensions": [
                    ".js",
                    ".jsx",
                    ".ts",
                    ".tsx"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In a file `src/components/elements/ProtectedRoutes/InviteRoute.tsx`, I have:

```
import routeNames from 'constants/routeNames';
import useRoles from 'hooks/roles';
import { ROLE } from 'shared/src/types/enums';
```

The app runs fine, but when I run lint, I get errors:

```
  2:24  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'constants/routeNames'    import/no-unresolved
  3:22  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'hooks/roles'             import/no-unresolved
  5:22  error  Unable to resolve path to module 'shared/src/types/enums'  import/no-unresolved
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you mean `import routeNames from './constants/routeNames';` instead of `import routeNames from 'constants/routeNames';`? I'm asking in comments because I don't know where your `constants/routeNames` module is supposed to come from here

Comment: For me this was the working solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/71874257/1770571

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should pass this config to eslint if you want to import your ts / tsx files without the extension.
The module directory is important here to resolve path inside ./src. If the module is not found inside src it will search inside node_modules

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx"],
      "moduleDirectory": ["src", "node_modules"]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oops! Something went wrong! :(

ESLint: 8.10.0

TypeError: "settings" for node must be an array

Comment: This fails with new Material UI syntax `@mui`

Answer (score 8):

If you get this error in a monorepo in VSCode it is probably because ESLint is looking for the tsconfig file in the incorrect folder and you should add a .vscode/settings.json with some configuration.

For example if you have a project located at workspaces/server:

```
{
  "eslint.workingDirectories": [
    { "directory": "workspaces/server", "changeProcessCWD": true },
  ]
}
```

to tell eslint about all the different sub-project folders

Comment: Worked as a charm after 2 days of trying! thanks :D

Comment: Bravo! After all it was a vscode issue. I spent hours debugging my eslintrc but found no luck. Thanks buddy!

Comment: This fix worked for me, thanks! Just a note that I needed a starting backslash (e.g. `/workspaces/server`.

Comment: Holy crap, after hours of banging my head into the wall this was it.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have defined custom [paths](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths) in your TypeScript config (usually `tsconfig.json`). The `import` plugin doesn't know about the correct location of the TypeScript config and hence cannot resolve those paths. What you need to do, is to specify the correct path to your TypeScript config via the `project` parameter in the [resolver options](https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/eslint-import-resolver-typescript#configuration):

```json
{
    ...
    "settings": {
        "import/resolver": {
            "project": "./my-path-to/tsconfig.json",
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Or if your `tsconfig.json` is located in your respository's root, set: `"project": {}`, see this GitHub issue: https://github.com/import-js/eslint-plugin-import/issues/1485

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps, I had similar issue but in a create-react-app project without typescript. What I had to do was add current directory to the moduleDirectory field, see below.

In my `.eslintrc.json` I added the following, please note I'm not using typescript files in my project:

```
"settings": {
"import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [".js", ".jsx"],
      "moduleDirectory": [".", "node_modules"]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using typescript, don't forget to include `.d.ts` to `extensions`.

```
"settings": {
  "import/resolver": {
    "node": {
      "extensions": [".ts", ".tsx", ".d.ts"], // add .d.ts here
      "moduleDirectory": ["src", "node_modules"]
    }
  }
}
```

I had a dependency that only exported `.d.ts` and the accepted answer was not working.

Adding `.d.ts` solved.