# getting 'Error: Cannot find module' when importing routes in Express

Tags: typescript, express

I have an ExpressJS app configured to use Typescript. I'm trying to add some routes. When I start the app I keep getting 'Error: Cannot find module 'routes/api'.

Here is my server.ts:

```
import express from "express";
import * as api from "routes/api";

const app = express(),
  port = 3000;
  // api = require("routes/api");

app.use("/", api.router);

app.listen(port);
```

Here is my routes/api.ts (updated):

```
import express from "express";
import { gql } from "@apollo/client";

const router = express.Router(),
  client = require("../apollo");

router.post("/graphql/:owner/:name", (req, res) => {
  client
    .query({
      query: gql`
        query($owner: String!, $name: String!) {
          repository(name: $name, owner: $owner) {
            latestRelease {
              name
              isLatest
              createdAt
              publishedAt
              updatedAt
              url
              tagName
              resourcePath
            }
          }
        }
      `
    })
    .then((result) =>
      console.log(`GraphQL response: ${JSON.stringify(result)}`)
    );
});
```

export default router;

My eslint config is in my package.json. I tried adding `import/extensions: 0` to the rules section as mentioned in other StackOverflow posts and adding `plugin:import/typescript` under the extends section. Nothing has worked.

Here's the eslint Config (updated) from my package.json:

```
"eslintConfig": {
    "settings": {
      "import/resolver": {
        "node": {
          "extensions": [
            ".js",
            ".ts"
          ]
        }
      }
    },
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": [
      "airbnb-base",
      "prettier",
      "eslint:recommended",
      "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended"
    ],
    "plugins": [
      "prettier",
      "@typescript-eslint"
    ],
    "env": {
      "es6": true,
      "browser": true
    },
    "rules": {
      "brace-style": [
        "error",
        "stroustrup"
      ],
      "comma-dangle": [
        "error",
        "never"
      ],
      "no-unused-vars": [
        "warn"
      ],
      "no-var": [
        "error"
      ],
      "one-var": [
        "error",
        "always"
      ],
      "prettier/prettier": [
        "error"
      ],
      "import/extensions": [
        "error",
        "ignorePackages",
        {
          "js": "never",
          "jsx": "never",
          "ts": "never",
          "tsx": "never"
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "prettier": {
    "trailingComma": "none",
    "arrowParens": "always",
    "jsxBracketSameLine": false
  }
```

I've also tried changing how router is exported. I've tried `module.exports = router`,`export default router` and `api = require("routes/api"` with no success. I don't understand why I'm getting the error when the file path is obviously correct. I'm still relatively new to Express. Any help would be appreciated.

Update:

Here is my folder structure:

```
-package.json
-node_modules
-server.ts
-apollo.ts
-routes
 -- api.ts
```

Comment: Hi, Can you please show your folder structure

Comment: I added my folder structure.

Comment: try this
import * as api from "./routes/api";

Answer (score 0):

Changing how api.ts is imported did help as @Priyanka suggested. I was still getting `Unable to resolve path to module` when I did `npm run lint`. To fully resolve the error I had to change the export syntax in api.ts to `export default router`. I also had to update eslint config section of my package.json. I followed the suggestions in this [StackOverflow post comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55198502/using-eslint-with-typescript-unable-to-resolve-path-to-module#comment97134671_55198502)