# VScode can't find project specific imports for `tsx` files, but typescript compiler finds them OK

Tags: reactjs, typescript, visual-studio-code, next.js

When I make a `jsx` component into `tsx`, VScode underlines the project-specific imports.

The following is from `components\molecules\WizardSteps.jsx`

### JSX

[image]

### TSX

The following is from `components\molecules\WizardSteps.tsx` after a rename:

The error is:

> Cannot find module 'components/atoms/Step' or its corresponding type declarations.

`components/atoms/Step.tsx` exists.

[image]

**However the typescript compiler doesn't complain and my projects build**. I'm using next.js so the typescript compiler is involved by the `next` command.

Here's my `tsconfig.json`

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": false,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "preserve"
  },
  "include": ["next-env.d.ts", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

I've read [the documentation on `include`](https://www.staging-typescript.org/tsconfig#include) and [`baseUrl`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#baseUrl) and confirmed that:

> **/ matches any directory nested to any level

So my includes should work.

Interestingly the issue only seems to occur with `tsx` files - `ts` files load project specific imports file.

**How can I make VScode happy about my typescript imports?**

Comment: How was `"components/atoms/Step"` getting resolved in the first case? Were you using https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/module-path-aliases? It doesn't seem to be in your `tsconfig.json` - did you have a `jsconfig.json`? And _are_ there type definitions for it?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I believe Next is just using `tsconfig.json` as mentioned, with the `baseUrl` and `include` options from `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: You have a `baseUrl` but no `paths`, so it's not clear to me how `Step` was being resolved _before_ the rename.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. I checked out https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#paths before asking here, but it didn't seem relevant as per the docs "This can be used to avoid long relative paths within your codebase." - I'm OK with long relative paths, I just want relative path to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since TypeScript builds the files, but VScode complains, it turns out the error is from `eslint` (despite the error not mentioning eslint).

Following steps from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56696478/123671, updating `.eslintrc` with the following:

```
extends: [
    "plugin:import/errors",
    "plugin:import/warnings",
    "plugin:import/typescript",
  ],
```

had made the errors go away.