# Can't import Firebase packages when using Typescript

Tags: typescript, google-cloud-functions

I recentyly shifted my Firebase Cloud functions from Javascript to Typescript. The ESLinter is always complaining about these imports:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions/v2';
import * as scheduler from 'firebase-functions/v2/scheduler';
import * as https from 'firebase-functions/v2/https';
import * as firestore from 'firebase-functions/v2/firestore';
```

I keep getting messages similar to this:

```
error  Unable to resolve path to module 'firebase-functions/v2'   import/no-unresolved
error  Unable to resolve path to module 'firebase-functions/v2/scheduler'  import/no-unresolved
...
...
```

Any idea on how to resolve this issue?
Here is how my .eslintrc.js look like:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    es6: true,
    node: true,
  },
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:import/errors',
    'plugin:import/warnings',
    'plugin:import/typescript',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    // 'google',
  ],
  parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  parserOptions: {
    project: ['tsconfig.json', 'tsconfig.dev.json'],
    sourceType: 'module',
  },
  ignorePatterns: [
    '/lib/**/*', // Ignore built files.
  ],
  plugins: ['promise', '@typescript-eslint', 'import'],
  rules: {
    // Removed rule "disallow the use of console" from recommended eslint rules
    'no-console': 'error',

    // Removed rule "disallow multiple spaces in regular expressions" from recommended eslint rules
    'no-regex-spaces': 'off',

    // Removed rule "disallow the use of debugger" from recommended eslint rules
    'no-debugger': 'off',

    // Removed rule "disallow unused variables" from recommended eslint rules
    'no-unused-vars': 'off',

    // Removed rule "disallow mixed spaces and tabs for indentation" from recommended eslint rules
    'no-mixed-spaces-and-tabs': 'off',

    // Removed rule "disallow the use of undeclared variables unless mentioned in /*global */ comments" from recommended eslint rules
    'no-undef': 'off',

    // Warn against template literal placeholder syntax in regular strings
    'no-template-curly-in-string': 1,

    // Warn if return statements do not either always or never specify values
    'consistent-return': 'error',

    // Warn if no return statements in callbacks of array methods
    'array-callback-return': 1,

    // Require the use of === and !==
    eqeqeq: 2,

    // Disallow the use of alert, confirm, and prompt
    'no-alert': 2,

    // Disallow the use of arguments.caller or arguments.callee
    'no-caller': 2,

    // Disallow null comparisons without type-checking operators
    'no-eq-null': 2,

    // Disallow the use of eval()
    'no-eval': 2,

    // Warn against extending native types
    'no-extend-native': 1,

    // Warn against unnecessary calls to .bind()
    'no-extra-bind': 1,

    // Warn against unnecessary labels
    'no-extra-label': 1,

    // Disallow leading or trailing decimal points in numeric literals
    'no-floating-decimal': 2,

    // Warn against shorthand type conversions
    'no-implicit-coercion': 1,

    // Warn against function declarations and expressions inside loop statements
    'no-loop-func': 1,

    // Disallow new operators with the Function object
    'no-new-func': 2,

    // Warn against new operators with the String, Number, and Boolean objects
    'no-new-wrappers': 1,

    // Disallow throwing literals as exceptions
    'no-throw-literal': 2,

    // Require using Error objects as Promise rejection reasons
    'prefer-promise-reject-errors': 2,

    // Enforce “for” loop update clause moving the counter in the right direction
    'for-direction': 2,

    // Enforce return statements in getters
    'getter-return': 2,

    // Disallow await inside of loops
    'no-await-in-loop': 2,

    // Disallow comparing against -0
    'no-compare-neg-zero': 2,

    // Warn against catch clause parameters from shadowing variables in the outer scope
    'no-catch-shadow': 1,

    // Disallow identifiers from shadowing restricted names
    'no-shadow-restricted-names': 2,

    // Enforce return statements in callbacks of array methods
    'callback-return': 2,

    // Require error handling in callbacks
    'handle-callback-err': 2,

    // Warn against string concatenation with __dirname and __filename
    'no-path-concat': 1,

    // Prefer using arrow functions for callbacks
    'prefer-arrow-callback': 1,

    // Return inside each then() to create readable and reusable Promise chains.
    // Forces developers to return console logs and http calls in promises.
    'promise/always-return': 2,

    // Enforces the use of catch() on un-returned promises
    'promise/catch-or-return': 2,

    // Warn against nested then() or catch() statements
    'promise/no-nesting': 1,
    'max-len': 'off',
    'quote-props': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any': 'off',
    '@typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars': 'off',
  },
};
```

Here is how my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "outDir": "lib",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es2017",
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": true,
  "include": ["src"]
}
```

Here is how my package.json looks like:

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "engines": {
    "node": "18"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint --ext .js,.ts .",
    "build": "tsc",
    "build:watch": "tsc --watch",
    "serve_dev": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions,storage,firestore,auth,pubsub,database --project oolfa-dev --import ./data_dev --export-on-exit ./data_dev",
    "serve_stg": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions,storage,firestore,auth,pubsub,database --project oolfa-stg --import ./data_stg --export-on-exit ./data_stg",
    "serve_prod": "npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions,storage,firestore,auth,pubsub,database --project oolfa-prod --import ./data_prod --export-on-exit ./data_prod",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "stop": "lsof -t -i:4000 -i:5001 -i:5002 -i:8080 -i:8085 -i:9000 -i:9099 -i:9199 -i:9299 | xargs kill -9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "^8.8.0",
    "@google-cloud/pubsub": "^3.7.0",
    "@sanity/client": "^6.4.12",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.7.0",
    "algoliasearch": "^4.20.0",
    "camelcase-keys": "^8.0.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^10.3.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^4.4.1",
    "googleapis": "^105.0.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "node-apple-receipt-verify": "^1.12.1",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.7",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.12.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.12.0",
    "eslint": "^8.9.0",
    "eslint-config-google": "^0.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^6.1.1",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^3.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Have a look at this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69746672/18265702) and [Github issue](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-node/discussions/1359).

Comment: Thanks.  I was able to solve the problem by looking at @RYFN  answer in the stackoverflow link.